# OpenCV HSV weird converted

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, hsv

I am working on project what detect hematoma from skin. I am having issue with color after convertion from RGB to HSV. My algorithm detect hematoma by its color.

With some images I have good results like here:

Original img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec9NC.jpg
Result img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrQrO.jpg

But with some images i have bad result like this:

Original img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9deG.jpg
Result img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F08Mc.jpg

The same original image after convertion to HSV: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suXbS.jpg

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really think someone is going to help you, without showing any src?

Comment: yes, I don't need exact code. I need just ideas or directions where to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your result image I think that you are only using the H channel of the original image in your algorithm. The false positive detection can inherit from that the some part of the healty skin has quite the same H value than the hematoma has. You can see on the qrey-scale image of H channel that both parts have similar values:

[image: H channel of original image]
The difference between the two parts is the saturation value. On the following image you can see the S channel of the original image and it shows perfectly that at the hematoma the saturation is much higher than at other the part of the arm:

[image]
This was expected because the hematoma has much stronger color than the healty skin has.

So, I suggest you to use both H and S channel in your algorithm that is **you have to take into account only that parts of H image where the S image contains high saturation values**. A possible and simple solution to do that is that you binarize both H and S images and with an AND operation you can execute this filtering:

**H image after binarisation:**
[image]
**S image after binarisation:**
[image]
**Image after H&S operation:**
[image]
You can see that on the result image only the hematoma part is white (except some noise but you can eliminate easily, for example by size or by morphological filtering).

EDIT

Important to note that binarization is one of most important (and sometimes also very complicated) step in the object detection algorithms namely binarization is the first highlight of the objects to detect.

If the the external conditions (lighting, color of objects etc.) do not change significantly from image to image you can use fix binaraziation thresholds. If this constant environment can not be issured you have to use more complicated methods. There are a lot of possibilies you can use, here you can read some examples:

- [Wikipedia - Thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29)
- [Wikipedia - Balanced histogram thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_histogram_thresholding)

Several solutions are based on the histogram analysis: on the histograms with objects there are always more local maximums which positions can vary depend on the environment and if you find them you can adapt the binarization threshold easily.

For example the histogram of the H channel of the original image is the following:
[image: Histrogram]
The first maximum belongs to the background, the second to the skin and the last to the hematome. It can be supposed that these 3 thresholds can be found in each image only their positions vary depend on the lighting or on other conditions. To put a threshold between the 2nd and the 3rd local maximum it can be a good choice to highlight the hematome.

Finally I offer you the read the following articel about thresholding in OpenCV:
[OpenCV - Thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. You are great. As you said I splited image to H S V and I worked just with H. if(t >= 150 && t<= 185){tblack.at<uchar>(i,j) = (uchar)255;} like this I was looking for color in range 150-185. Do you think how can I mix those two methods? Use color and also bitwise_and(planes[0], planes[1], final_img);? Also should I use Adaptive Thresholding to binarize img?

Comment: I have done some tests and I found out that my simple binarization threshold( planes[0], img, 108, 255,THRESH_BINARY ); with set values are not so good with other images. Is there some smart threshold that can calculate it automatically from input image?

Comment: I am glad that it works. I edited my answer and wrote there some information about thresholding.

Comment: great, thank you. I will read them. Also do you think that I can contact you on skype or facebook if there will be some part what i wont understand?

Comment: I hope that your solution works now. If you have more questions, ask them here at Stackoverflow, as my experience you will get fast and perfect answers.